# Importar Polymer con Bower en Django

Tags: django, polymer, bower

Estoy usando cloud9, y tengo un proyecto en Django en el que tengo que realizar la vista con Polymer.
Sigo el manual de instalación de bower: https://django-bower.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

Instalo correctamente bower, y instalo polymer(google maps) con bower correctamente (veo que se genera la estructura de carpetas. siguiendo este ejemplo (http://www.desarrolloweb.com/articulos/mapas-google-custom-elements-polymer.html).

```
    <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="bower_components/google-map/google-map.html">
```

Pero no me encuentra las url: https://(website)/data/bower_components/google-map/google-map.html Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

La ruta donde están los compomenents es: /home/ubuntu/workspace siendo esta ruta la ruta del proyecto.

¿Como indico al template que tiene que cargar desde esa ruta los componentes de bower?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Los estás llamando con ruta relativa a la página que consultas, ten cuidado con eso. Por otro lado, la [documentación oficial de Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/howto/static-files/) debería ser suficiente para lo que quieres hacer. No hay forma de saber si tu configuración es correcta y en tus plantillas, casi con seguridad podemos afirmar que la ruta no es adecuada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django tiene su manera de manejar archivos estaticos (css, javascript, imagenes, etc) tenes que entenderla bien primero: [Static Files Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial06/). Puede ser un poco complicado entenderla al principio pero cuando la entiendes ves que tiene mucho sentido.

En resumen, en django para que podas cargar archivos estaticos tienen que estar en un directorio especial por defecto 'static' debido a eso tenes que configurar bower usando el archivo [.bowerrc](http://bower.io/docs/config/) para que bower te 'instale' las librerias en tu carpeta static correspondiente para te quede algo asi: **/static/bower_components/...** una ves hecho eso vas a poder cargar tus archivos asi:

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<script src="{% static 'bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js' %}"></script>
<link rel="import" href="{% static 'bower_components/google-map/google-map.html' %}">
```

al final cuando django renderiza la template usando la configuracion por defecto para static files esto:

```
<script src="{% static 'bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js' %}"></script>
```

se convierte en esto:

```
<script src="/static/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Gracias! Era por eso, estaba referenciando mal la ruta y por eso no me lo cargaba.

Comment: De nada, me alegro que te funcionara